# Is this a Pythonic way to call instance methods?

Tags: python

The below code works, but is clunky, and I want the hippo instance to take on five values, not exchange the last two in the 'description' method for the first two in the init method, and the class variable, 'is_alive'.

```
class Animal(object):
    is_alive = True

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def description(self, location, diet):
        print location
        print diet

hippo = Animal("Jimmy",3)
#hippo = Animal.description(hippo, "zoo", "plants") #errors 


print hippo.name
print hippo.age
print hippo.is_alive

hippo = Animal.description(hippo, "zoo", "plants")  #instance takes on 
#new values -- don't want that; want to append to init values
print hippo

>>>
Jimmy
3
True
zoo
plants
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: your method only prints without assigning values

Comment: Serge, that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hippo` is your instance of `Animal`, and you should invoke the function like:

```
hippo.description("zoo", "plants")
```

Here I provide an example:

```
class Animal:
    def desc(self):
        print("desc is invoked...")

    @staticmethod
    def description():
        print("description is invoked..")

hippo = Animal()
hippo.desc()
Animal.description()
```

Comment: @ArinEkandem glad it helps. please check it as the answer :)